# Where is the flash memory for this IP camera board?

Tags: integrated-circuit, flash, camera, soc, flash-memories

I just opened an Escam IP camera and this is the main board.

You can see the HI3516 SoC + H5TQ1G63EFR RAM + that thing with adhesive that in the second photo I took off and you can see it's a TMS1102NL which according to https://www.yoycart.com/Product/628493863187/ is a network transformer. That MK24C16A looks like a small EEPROM.

On the other side we have 2 small microcontrollers: 8041NL 1625SA4T and 25Q128FVSG but I couldn't find anything about them on google.

So where is the flash memory?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure 25Q128FVSG is a microcontroller..?

Comment: 25Q128FVSG is flash. Came up right away in Google. SoC has no onboard flash. Weird.

Comment: @DKNguyen - yes that was a wink wink tip for the OP. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 25Q128 is large enough SPI flash chip to contain the firmware.